# Make return type of parent class to be covariant

Tags: java, tree

I have following class hierarchy:

```java
public class Node<T extends Comparable>
{
  private T element;
  private Node<T> rightChild;
  private Node<T> leftChild;

  public Node(T element)
  {
    this.element = element;
  }

  public Node()
  {
  }

  public T getElement()
  {
    return element;
  }

  public void setElement(T element)
  {
    this.element = element;
  }

  public Node<T> getRightChild()
  {
    return rightChild;
  }

  public void setRightChild(Node<T> rightChild)
  {
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
  }

  public Node<T> getLeftChild()
  {
    return leftChild;
  }

  public void setLeftChild(Node<T> leftChild)
  {
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
  }
}


public class RedBlackNode<T extends Comparable> extends Node<T>
{
  public RedBlackNode(T element)
  {
    super(element);
    this.isRed = true;
  }

  private boolean isRed;

  public boolean isRed()
  {
    return isRed;
  }

  public void setRed(boolean red)
  {
    isRed = red;
  }

  @Override
  public RedBlackNode<T> getRightChild()
  {
    return (RedBlackNode<T>) super.getRightChild();
  }

  @Override
  public RedBlackNode<T> getLeftChild()
  {
    return (RedBlackNode<T>) super.getLeftChild();
  }
}
```

Is it possible in child class RedBlackNode use method `getRightChild` so it will return `RedBlackNode` and not the parent `Node`? One possible solution for me is to override this method in `RedBlackNode` but are there any more elegant ways to do that?

**Update**
I added code how it will look with overriding but not sure if there are any scope for improvements:)

Comment: I thing the overriding is the more elegant solution here

Comment: this way you can attach `Node` child objects to `RedBlackNode` ones. Is there any reason why you need `Node`?

Comment: do you mean to use composition here instead of inheritance?

Comment: @user3298327 I just mean - will you ever need to use the super class (Node) or only RedBlackNode? Perhaps you don't need this class hierarchy at all

Comment: actually, I need such hierarchy because some of my trees don't need to use RedBlackNode...

Answer (score 0):

My opinion common interface for all the tree node type and specialize will implement the common interface.If required the client api can call to specialized method by typecast

```
public interface TreeNode<V> {

    public V getValue();

    public TreeNode<V> getLeftChield();

    public TreeNode<V> getRightChield();
   public void setLeftChield(TreeNode<V> treeNode);

public void setRightChield(TreeNode<V> treeNode);
}
class Node<V> implements TreeNode<V> {

        V value;
        int count;
        TreeNode<V> left;
        TreeNode<V> right;
        TreeNode<V> parent;

        public Node(V value, TreeNode<V> parent) {
            this.value = value;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public TreeNode<V> getLeftChield() {
            return left;
        }

        public TreeNode<V> getRightChield() {
            return right;
        }



        public void setLeftChield(TreeNode<V> leftNode) {
            left = leftNode;
        }

        public void setRightChield(TreeNode<V> rightNode) {
            right = rightNode;
        }


    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that it's answer on my question. So let's imagine that I identified this interface and implemented it by my class `Node`. After that, I understood that I need to have `RedBlackNode` which from my opinion should extend `Node` class. How adding interface will resolve my problem?